# config error (There was an error while performing this operation)

Tags: asp.net, iis, server

When I want to go module section in IIS I got this error.

[image]

And I also installed  URL rewrite module. I know there is problem in  web.config file but I don't understand where is the problem.

here is my web.config file

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RasaBack.dll"   
              stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
              hostingModel="InProcess" />
  <aspNetCore processPath=".\RasaBack.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false"stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
</system.webServer>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error removed when I installed .net core husting bundle V3.1 showed me the full error.
[image]

And I see I have two  **aspNetCore**

```
 <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RasaBack.dll"    
              stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
              hostingModel="InProcess" />
  <aspNetCore processPath=".\RasaBack.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
</system.webServer>
```

**Then I removed on of those the error has gone.**

Answer (score 7):

Please make sure you have installed Dotnet core hosting bundle.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

Comment: This. In my case I also needed to install https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite because I had added a reference to the `rewrite` module.

Answer (score 1):

To run the asp.net core site in iis you need to install the .net core hosting bundle and .NET Core Runtime.

you could download both the things from the below link based on your version:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core