# IIS 10.0 Detailed Error 500.19 Error Code: 0x8007000d

Tags: asp.net-core, localhost, angular8, iis-10

After publish my project in local IIS server, When I execute the install program: http://localhost/codeIIS/ I get an error 500.19 Internal Server error.
Here is my Platform Details:

- IIS-10.0
- Windows 10 x64bit OS

In my web.config file code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\CONSOLIDATION PORTAL.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 8240d3ab-7972-48e2-91ac-f9f57451ae7e-->
```

The error is Here:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsA39.png)

How to fix that error. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you don't install the .Net core hosting bundle. I suggest you could downloaded it and install it and test again. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

Comment: @BrandoZhang I installed urlrewrite.exe, aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.10-win-x64.exe and windowsdesktop-runtime-5.0.0-win-x64.exe. But Error is not fixing.

Comment: Why you installed the url rewrite?  Is your web.config file completely? Do you use url rewrite in your application? If possible, please post the whole config file which path is wwwroot\xxxIIS\web.config.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19 (0x8007000d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Answer (score 0):

From the microsoft documents page -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x8007000d

This is due to malformed XML in your webconfig. Should there be a space between consolidation and portal here? -

```
processPath=".\CONSOLIDATION PORTAL.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete .vs hidden folder and execute again.

Greetings