# HTTP 500.19 Error for Dot Net 5.0 WebAPI Application

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI install on a server of mine and I keep getting the following error when browsing it:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

I set this up using Dot Net 5.0 WebAPI and I have it installed in the latest version of IIS after publishing to a directory.

Here's what my `web.config` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\akmazio-api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 3b944703-a011-4408-9581-8c919ba4ed0e-->
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Access the page on that server locally so that you can see the detailed error page with a 8-digit error code, like `8xxxxxxx`. That can tell you which existing discussions match the issue you met.

Comment: @LexLi 0x8007000d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19 (0x8007000d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Comment: @LexLi see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67202366/1694767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the .NET Core Hosting Bundle needed to be installed, the application needed to be modified so Swagger works correctly by commenting out the `env.IsDevelopment()` if statement in the `Startup.cs` `Configure()` function, the following needed to be added to `Startup.cs` `Configure()` function:

```
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
```

the public settings needed to be set to

```
Target location: C:\publish\directory
Delete existing files: true
Configuration: Release
Target Framework: net5.0
Target Runtime: win-x64
Deployment Mode: Self-Contained
```

And IIS needs to be configured so that the Application Pool has No Managed Code and runs using Network Service.

And voila I go to http://localhost/swagger/index.html and everything is now working correctly!

Answer (score 3):

Publish Core to IIS requires installation of .NET Core Hosting Bundle, for more information about it, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

If you have installed the .NET Core host bundle according to the above steps, but this problem is still not resolved. I suggest you try to deploy a core template application, I suspect there may be a problem with your application.

In addition, you can also use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to troubleshoot this issue.