# HTTP 500 error That’s odd... the website can’t display this page

Tags: iis

I am trying to setup a web API but can't seem to get the API to work in IIS.

When I debug the default ASP .netCore API weatherforcast example from Visual Studio 2019 everything works locally as expected. But as soon as I publish the project and more it to the default webpage folder in IIS, I can't seem to be able to open the web interface any more and postman doesn't communicate with it any more as well, it is a windows 10 environment.

The Error that I get is : HTTP 500 error

That’s odd... the website can’t display this page

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19 (0x8007000d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Comment: What have you done on IIS? Did you install asp.net core host bundle correctly and give enough permission to application pool identity? Check log and event viewer to get the sub status code and detailed error message.