# apparently netcore is not recognized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, http-status-code-500

I have a web application built in NetCore 3.1, application runs fine in my localhost and other server, but in production server don't. In production server we've installed Netcore 3.1, and 5, the webpage displays the following error:
[image]

I've checked netcore in properly installed too:
[image]

I have tried almost everything to run the website but nothing seems to run.
Another actions I've made:

- restart server
- order the environment variables
- set permissions to instalation folder

Comment: Did you install the [Windows Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19 (0x8007000d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Comment: Did you install url rewrite in production server? How do you migrate the application from test server to production server and what's different between test server and production server?

Answer (score 0):

at the end, I don't know what happend exactly, previously I had installed windows hosting bundle for net core 3.1 and 5, but I've just installed the bundle for version 5 again and it worked. know the server is online again.