# HTTP Error 500.19 - internal server error code 0x8007000d

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10

I created an ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API project. I can execute and run the application in IIS Express. If I deploy the app, then I get the following error:

```
Server Error in Application "application name"
HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error
HRESULT: 0x8007000d
Description of HRESULT
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

The official [MS support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x8007000d) referenced two causes:

> This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config
> file contains a malformed or unidentified XML element. IIS can't
> identify the XML elements of the modules that are not installed. For
> example, IIS URL Rewrite module.
>
> Resolution
>
> Use one of the following methods:
>
> ```
> Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file.
> Check the unidentified XML elements, and then install the relevant IIS modules.
> ```

I installed IIS URL Rewrite module without a effect.
[image]

My web.config comes with my build/deploy process. For configurations I use the appsettings.json. So I don't know if and what have propably to change in my web.config. Any suggestions?

...\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApi\web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: f659debd-cac7-4ce5-b2fe-d1a440a87811-->
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19 (0x8007000d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should install hosting bundle version of .Net to add support .Net core runtime in IIS on server

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.13-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

all downloads:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: after install the error change to "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." Any suggestion?