# .NET6 Web Application Deployment to IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, .net-6.0

I have published .NET6 application to IIS using VS2022. When I go to the site it is giving me error.
I can run/debug it from Visual Studio
**Error Message**
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
[image]

Try creating site and deploy code. I want to be publish site working on IIS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19 (0x8007000d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may be caused by IIS not being able to parse the xml configuration node aspNetCore in `Web.config`.

You need to check if ASP.NET Core module is not installed, if yes, just download and install Hosting Bundle can be solved. Check for `aspnetcore.dll` in `%windir%\System32\inetsrv`. This document is about [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0)